# I want to change className of a div after push

Tags: reactjs

I am new in react, I want to change className after when I push in to `this.displayData2 array`. I have already set a state `changeClass: false` and I am changing it to `true` after `onClick event`, as per change in `changeClass` state I want to change my ClassName from `ani` to `newani`.

**here is my code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.displayData1 = [0];
    this.displayData2 = [1];
    this.state = {
      showData1: this.displayData1,
      showData2: this.displayData2,
      Alldata: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
      store: [],
      changeClass: false,
      ani: false
    }
    this.UpdateData = this.UpdateData.bind(this);
    this.setNew = this.setNew.bind(this);
  }

  UpdateData() {
    this.displayData2.push(<div className={this.state.changeClass ? 'ani' : 'newani'} key={this.state.Alldata.shift()}>2</div>);
    this.setState({
      showData2: this.displayData2,
      changeClass: true
    })

    setTimeout(this.setNew, 1000);

  }

  setNew() {
    this.state.store.push(this.displayData1.shift());
    this.displayData1.push(this.displayData2.shift());
    this.setState({
      showData1: this.displayData1,
      store: this.state.store,
      changeClass: false,
      ani: true
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App wrapper">
        <div className={"left box hidden" + (this.state.changeClass ? '' : ' active')}>
          <div className="ani">{this.displayData1}</div>
        </div>
        <div className={"right box visible" + (this.state.changeClass ? '' : ' active') + (this.state.ani ? ' a' : ' b')}>
          <div className={this.state.ani ? '' : 'ani'}>{this.displayData2}</div>
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.UpdateData}>getData</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Comment: Can you please describe your problem? What happens?

Comment: I am just want to change the class name from ani to newani when I push that div to displayData2 array

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this:

```
className={this.state.something}
```

or with backticks

```
className={`${this.state.something}`}
```

After that, you just change state `this.setState({something: "newName"})`

Comment: can you please give me a little example of your code.

Comment: here is my code 

default state value:  changeClass: 'ani'

UpdateData() {
  this.displayData2.push(<div className={this.state.changeClass}>some data</div>);
  setTimeout(this.setNew, 5000);
} 

setNew() {
this.setState({
  changeClass: 'newani'
});
}

but is not working